# Обособление словосочетания «ко всеобщему удовлетворению»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Проблема престолонаследия(,) ко всеобщему удовлетворению(,) чудесным образом решилась.

Нужны ли обозначенные запятые?

P. S. Есть ли стилистические или иные комментарии к этому предложению?

Comment: Попутно задался вопросом: "ко всеобщему" или "к всеобщему"? В Нацкорпусе 420:224 в пользу "ко всеобщему".

Comment: Я склоняюсь к **ко всеобщему** (в подтверждение — ссылка в моем ответе).

Answer (score 4):

1. В списках вводных слов и выражений ([Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-alphabet) и [Памятка редактора](https://baddcat.livejournal.com/92274.html)) словосочетание "ко всеобщему удовлетворению" отсутствует.
   Однако оно "нашлось" в статье [Синтаксические признаки научного стиля](http://file:///C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/6+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20(1).pdf):
   ...эмоциональное отношение (к сожалению, ко всеобщему  удовлетворению, видите ли, согласитесь, представьте себе).
2. Если бы мне пришлось расставлять знаки препинания, то я бы поставила тире:
   *Проблема престолонаследия — ко всеобщему удовлетворению — чудесным образом решилась.*

Мне думается, словосочетание (имеет значение *к счастью, к радости*) дополняет, усиливает отношение автора к тому, что *проблема решилась чудесным образом* (положительные чувства **уже** присутствуют).

3. *Но вот наконец, ко всеобщему  удовлетворению, сильный ураган  разогнал
   тучи в ночь с 11 на  12 декабря, и Луна, сильно ущербленная, ярко засияла на
   черном фоне неба.*
   Ж. Верн. Вокруг Луны

*"Работа, действительно, была сложная, могу подтвердить это, но, ко всеобщему удовлетворению, она завершена", - сказала министр на рабочей встрече с главой правительства.*
Из доклада Т. Голиковой В. Путину (17. 06. 2011)

Я предполагаю, что обособление словосочетания зависит от его расположения в предложении. **После** глагола выражение чаще всего имеет значение обстоятельства (*как? каким образом?*) и запятых не требует:
*Все закончилось ко всеобщему удовлетворению простыми теплыми объятиями и такими же теплыми выражениями всеобщей радости...* (И. Брилева)

Answer (score 3):

Естественно, нужны. К сожалению, к счастью, к несчастью и т.п. – сюда подходит и "ко всеобщему удовлетворению". Вводное сочетание.

Но! Проблема престолонаследия решилась ко всеобщему удовлетворению. Здесь это уже не вводное, а обстоятельство. Решилась (как?) ко всеобщему удовлетворению.